# Change action bar to toolbar, and now I am having force closes. What am I doing wrong here?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-appcompat, android-toolbar

I followed this tutorial http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html. I have dependencies correct, added this to my layout file `toolbar.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/simplecolor" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And this in main activity:

```
 import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Why am I getting a force close? It was working well with the normal action bar, but after changing it to a toolbar I am experiencing force close on application startup. I am new to android coding, please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine. But you missed app:theme to set toolbar as actionbar.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_height=”wrap_content”
    android:layout_width=”match_parent”
    android:minHeight=”@dimen/triple_height_toolbar”
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Change the following in styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>

</style>
```